# Does NVIDIA's OpenCL compiler support something like --generate-line-info?

Tags: command-line, opencl, nvidia, debug-information

When (dynamically) compiling CUDA code to PTX, you can pass the `--generate-line-info` command-line parameter, and get a bunch of `.loc` entries in your PTX, which relate PTX locations to source file locations.

Is something like this also available when compiling OpenCL code into PTX (`clBuildProgram`) on NVIDIA platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Try `-nv-line-info`.  I can't find documentation for it, but the compiler accepts it and generates exactly what you are looking for.
The option is notable absent from their  [official OpenCL compiler options extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/nv/cl_nv_compiler_options.txt).

NOTE: Your mileage may vary. A few years ago when I fiddled around with this the mapping accuracy was not great compared to CUDA +`nvcc`. Maybe they've improved things though.

Comment: Well... 1. It worked, except that the line info basically uses the same function name always, `info_string0`.