# What flags does the NVIDIA OpenCL compiler support beyond the OpenCL standard ones?

Tags: compilation, opencl, nvidia, compiler-options

The CUDA 3.0 toolkit documentation [listed](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/toolkit/docs/opencl_extensions/cl_nv_compiler_options.txt) several flags NVIDIA's OpenCL compiler accepts, as an extension beyond what the OpenCL standard mandates:

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `-cl-nv-maxrregcount <N>` | Max number of registers a kernel (or device function?) may use); passed on to ptxas as --maxrregcount |
| `-cl-nv-opt-level <N>` | Code optimization level. |
| `-cl-nv-verbose` | Enable verbose mode. |

But I know there are others. For example, the clcc project mentions `cl-nv-arch` and `cl-nv-cstd` (which actually regards the OpenCL C version targeted). I vaguely recall one flag in particular which turns off support for grids/block sizes beyond CUDA's natively-supported grid and block sizes. How can I determine those extra flags, in a recent NVIDIA OpenCL runtime version?

Answer (score 0):

This one is due to @Tim, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68383795/1593077):

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `-nv-line-info` | Generates information about the locations in the source files corresponding to PTX instructions; more-or-less the same as the NVCC command-line option `--generate-line-info`. |